# Is the blue button outline in dialog windows removed in Yosemite when using Tab (keyboard navigation)?

Tags: macos

Being a zealous user of keyboard navigation, I activated `All controls` in `Full Keyboard Access` (`Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts`).

In Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks I was used to having a blue outline on the button/input box that was active, and I could see it move to the next one when pressing Tab.

After updating my OS to 10.10 Yosemite, the outline (now grey) is gone on specific button types and for the large part I cannot see which button is active anymore. When pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> repeatedly in a "Save" window the text boxes and switch buttons highlight but drop-downs and regular buttons don't, even though they are active (i.e. pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> will act as if I clicked them with a mouse).

Do more users experience this behavior, or is it just me? If it's just me, does anyone know how to fix this? If it's not just me, where do I report this bug?

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be indeed a bug; I reported it on bugreporter.apple.com, the openrdar is here: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5297887323881472

Also, the latest Photoshop CC 2014 seem to be working ok

Comment: Hey Leo, thanks. What's your experience with reporting OS X bugs on Open Radar? As Open Radar is not owned by Apple I'm wondering how actively they monitor and reply on bug reports there.

Comment: @CarbonBase Apple has their own private bug system called rdar. These bugs are not publicly accessible, therefore there is now way to see if a certain bug was reported before etc.

OpenRdar is an attempt to fix that a bit by providing a manual system of submitting bugs you have reported (and updating them if their status changes), so that others my have a look at the bug.

Comment: Are there any known workarounds or utility apps that address this issue?

Comment: As far as I know recompiling the apps with a current version of xCode fixes the problem. This is of course only a solution for apps that are open-source

Comment: Came here looking for a fix to this problem in Cornerstone (SVN Client). Checking for updates fixed the issue; somehow it didn't notify me earlier than an update with Yosemite compatibility was now available. Hopefully all other apps will be fixed this way over time.

Answer (score -1):

Go into Preferences, Keyboard, Shortcuts - 
Full Keyboard Access.

Comment: What improvements this answer brings over the existing ones?

Comment: Hi Tom, I think you missed my first sentence: "Being a zealous user of keyboard navigation, I activated All controls in Full Keyboard Access (Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts)."

Comment: Thanks Tom. This totally fixed the problems I was having. Not sure why you were down voted. Hopefully others will scroll down and see your solution.

Answer (score -2):

Fot me the apple apps seems to handle the tabbing as expected, but other apps, creative suite for instance doesnt get it..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This does not provide an answer to the question. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.